What is spring security's default parent ProviderManager?
Custom Filter code.
class TokenVerifyFilter(
    private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager,
    private val authenticationEntryPoint: SecurityAuthenticationEntryPoint
) : OncePerRequestFilter() {
    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        // ...
        val authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(BearerTokenAuthenticationToken(token))
        // ...
    }
}

I registered two AuthenticationProvider.
@Bean
fun authenticationManager(
    http: HttpSecurity,
    loginAuthenticationProvider: LoginAuthenticationProvider,
    bearerTokenAuthenticationProvider: BearerTokenAuthenticationProvider
): AuthenticationManager {
    val authenticationManagerBuilder =
        http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder::class.java)
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(loginAuthenticationProvider).authenticationProvider(bearerTokenAuthenticationProvider)
    return authenticationManagerBuilder.build()
}

BearerTokenAuthenticationProvider#authenticate throw an exception, This exception extends from AuthenticationException.
Then it entered an infinite loop. I found that the problem occurred in ProviderManager.
public class ProviderManager implements AuthenticationManager, MessageSourceAware, InitializingBean {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // ...
        for (AuthenticationProvider provider : getProviders()) {
            // ...
            try {
                result = provider.authenticate(authentication);
                if (result != null) {
                    copyDetails(authentication, result);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // 1. catch AuthenticationException
            catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
                lastException = ex;
            }
        }
        if (result == null && this.parent != null) {
            // Allow the parent to try.
            try {
                // 2. Trapped in a loop here, Return to the first step.
                parentResult = this.parent.authenticate(authentication);
                result = parentResult;
            }
            // ...
        }
    }

}

It looks like when ProviderManager catches the exception and tries to call the parent AuthenticationManager. But still reinvoked itself?
I use org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:6.2.3
I finally found the solution.
authenticationManagerBuilder.parentAuthenticationManager(null)

But when this is set, the exception thrown will be caught by dispatcherServlet instead of continuing to execute the next filter. How to fix it?
I didn't set the parent ProviderManager, so why is the parent ProviderManager the same as ProviderManager?
